# Adverb or a conjunction?

Tags: adverbs

Good afternoon everyone!

I was doing a syntactic analysis of the sentence below and stuck at the adverb:

*Bring as many books as there are students*

(you) ---> subject

bring ---> verb

as many books as there are students ---> object, where:

books ---> "the core" of the object

**as many as there are students** ---> adverbial something:(

So I have two questions:

1) Are we dealing with a simple sentence here?

2) Can we break down the adverb any further?

Thank you in advance:)

Seva

Comment: You can presumably break down *as many [books] as there are students*, since it could be replaced by *as many [books] as **possible*** or *as many as **five** [books]*, for example.

Comment: Okay, I've got this one, it is a complex sentence with the adverbial of degree

Comment: No, it's not a simple sentence; it's an equative _as...as_ construction. These involve two clauses, heavily reduced, and a comparison of equality between them. In this case, the equative is used to denote the quantifier for _books_, so the whole thing is modifying the direct object NP. The equative construction itself can be broken down, but not by parsing parts of speech; _as_, for instance, is used as a coordinate correlative conjunction in this construction, but  normally _as_ is a subordinate conjunction. In any event, the constituent it heads is a quantifier.

Comment: As you might have gathered, John Lawler ranks above most people teaching English in schools. Above many people who have written grammars. So don't expect sweetness and light if you reproduce his explanation; your interlocutor might not understand it.

Comment: Thank you, John Lawer, the "complex-simple" bit is clear now, but could you, please, expand on why the "as" here is coordinate?

Comment: Oh, I might have parsed it incorrectly...Another try: BRING [subject] AS [first part of the correlative conjunction] MANY BOOKS [direct object noun phrase] AS [second part of the correlate conjunction joining an independent clause] THERE [dummy subject] ARE STUDENTS [predicate]. Does it make sense? Thank you:)

Comment: On second thought, two independent clauses, joined by a coordinate conjunction (and, but, or) can be separated by a coma, resulting in two "self-sufficient" stand-alone sentences as in: "I fell down the staircase and hurt my arm". Yet, we can't do the same for "Bring as much books as you can". Do you think It might only be correlative?